# SQL Query to find the next staus and get time between them

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Im arguing with a sql query in bigquery, i have a table with multiple ticket numbers along with all the rest of the data from the tickets. Im trying to find out who long a ticket sits in a particular state.

My data looks like this:

TicketNumber | DateUpdated | State | Notes | .....

Im trying to get this:

TicketNumber | DateUpdated | State | NextState | DateChanged

Ive been playing with various different queries but i always seem to get duplicates. like this one:

```
SELECT distinct allinc.TicketNumber as inc, allinc.state, DateChanged, allinc.TicketNumber, nextupdate
FROM `incidents` allinc
left outer join (
select *, CAST(DateUpdated AS datetime) as DateChanged, state as DateChanged from `incidents`
) resinc
on allinc.TicketNumber = resinc.TicketNumber and CAST(resinc.DateChanged AS datetime) > CAST(allinc.TicketNumber AS datetime) 
where allinc.state = 'Awaiting User' 
order by inc
```

The end goal is to get the total time the ticket was set to 'Awaiting User' but this can be multiple times for each ticket.

Any advice would be great.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (mysql, sql server, postgres, oracle, etc..)?

Comment: @BobBryden . . . Sample data and desired results would also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are describing `lead()`:

```
select i.*,
       lead(state) over (partition by ticketnumber order by dateupdated) as next_state,
       lead(dateupdated) over (partition by ticketnumber order by dateupdated) as next_dateupdated
from incidents i;
```

Comment: you sir are a hero!

I had never heard of lead, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you normalize your table first. I think it would be best if the ticket_details are on one table and the ticket_states will be on another.

**ticket_details** (PK TicketNumber, other_details)

**ticket_state** (PK TicketNumber, PK DateCreated, DateUpdated, State)

This way, a certain ticket can have as many states as needed. As for change in state, you can insert a new record in ticket_states with the same TicketNumber and the DateCreated of the new record will be the DateUpdated of the previous record.

For the query for getting the total time it is in a given state such as 'Awaiting User', you can probably do something like this:

```
SELECT TicketNumber, State, SUM(DateDiff)
FROM
        (SELECT ticket_details.TicketNumber, ticket_state.State, DATEDIFF(DateUpdated,DateCreated) AS DateDiff FROM ticket_details
        LEFT JOIN ticket_state
        ON ticket_details.TicketNumber = ticket_state.TicketNumber) TableDetailState
WHERE State = 'Awaiting User'
GROUP BY TicketNumber
```